# Find the maximum $k$ that this $14$ vertices $3$ regular graph is $k$-connected

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to find the maximum $k$ such that this graph is $k$-connected.

[image: click here for the graph]

By Menger's Theorem, its k should be 3 but I can't find any three vertices whose removal will disconnect the graph.

[image: After removal]

Answer (score 1):

Removing 3 neighbours of any vertex disconnects the graph so $k \leq 3$.

Comment: Hey I totally agree, but I am confused because after removing three vertices, the graph still looks connected (see my updated picture). Did I do something wrong?

Comment: The circled vertex is a component so the graph is disconnected. There's no path from the circled vertex to any of the other vertices, the graph has two components after removing the three adjacent vertices.

Comment: Ahhh! I see!! I naively removed the circled vertex as I removed the edges incident to it. Thanks a lot!